# How can I loosen tight Trapezius muscles?

Tags: computers, ergonomics, posture, muscle-relaxers

I'd also appreciate ways of [preventing them from becoming tight](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/10161/how-can-i-prevent-muscles-from-becoming-tight), specifically when working at the computer. Thanks!